# Max depth of Binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to find the max depth of binary search tree. I found a code.

```
int maxDepth(struct node* node) { 
  if (node==NULL) { 
    return(0); 
  } 
  else { 
    // compute the depth of each subtree 
    int lDepth = maxDepth(node->left); 
    int rDepth = maxDepth(node->right);
    // use the larger one 
    if (lDepth > rDepth) return(lDepth+1); 
    else return(rDepth+1); 
  } 
}
```

I want to know that how come node->left would return 1 ?

Is it by default ? The code is easy but I do not know from where is the answer coming, can anyone explain me please ?

Comment: Tagging language will help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how come node->left would return 1?"

Comment: @EJP, I don't see why it won't work if either subtree is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this tree:

[A]

/ \

[B] [C]

maxDepth will be called for [B] with NULL, and for [C] with NULL, both return zero and so the recursive call ends up returning 0+1.

If you had a node [D] under [C] then the call to [D] maxDepth will return NULL and D will return 0+1, then the recursion will keep scaling up and [C] will receive 0+1 and will some +1, returning a maxDepth of 2 which is bigger than the depth of the branch that holds [B] which is 1 so maxDepth of 2 is returned from the complete recursion.

Answer (score 1):

When `node` points to a leaf, both its `node->left` and `node->right` is `NULL`. So `maxDepth()` both return `0`. So the current recursion for this leaf just returns with depth `0 + 1 = 1.`

You can prove its correctness.

**Initialization**

When the node is `NULL`, it returns `0`. And it's true that an empty tree has depth `0`.
When the node is leaf, it returns `1`. As just explained.

**Maintenance**

If a node exists(not `NULL`) and we know the depths of its children, the depth of this node will be the `max(depth of left, depth of right) + 1`. And that's what returned.

**Termination**

It will terminate because when it reaches the leaf, the recursion will stop getting deeper and return. When the whole recursion finishes, `maxDepth(root)` returns the depth of the `root`.